# AngularJS Google Closure Compiler with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I'm trying to create an extern of Google's API to work in the Google Closure App. The javascript I am using is here:

https://apis.google.com/js/client.js

With the extern being generated here:

http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/index.html

And I am trying to have the extern named `gapi`. The problem is the extern is always empty. Is there another way of getting the extern for google's api?

Comment: I haven't seen that externs extractor before. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with hand-written externs. Googling around a bit, I found [this one](http://git.yathit.com/ydn-base/src/91312cc1bb729e12d8077cc796d4aaa71164dfe8/externs/gapi.js?at=master) which looks reasonably correct, at least at first glance.